# Is it possible to move/distribute the cuda compiler (nvcc) after installation?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cuda

We are starting work on a CUDA/C++ project. We are using several dev machines running Windows and Linux, as well as a few CI servers. We have a CMake project as well as a pre-specified local directory for pre-compiled third party libraries (e.g. `C:\thirdparty`).

**My question is: is there any way to just copy `nvcc.exe` and associated binaries into that third-party directory? Or does each developer and build machine need to run the CUDA installer?**

I've been following this blog post: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/building-cuda-applications-cmake/

Their solution worked for me after installing CUDA locally. However it doesn't seem like you can move the nvcc binaries out of their default install location and still have everything build. I copied `C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0` to `C:\thirdparty\CUDA\10.0.` Next I called `set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:/thirdparty/CUDA/10.0/bin/nvcc.exe")` in my `CMakeLists.txt`. CMake fails with:

> AddCudaCompileDeps:
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe
>   /E /nologo /showIncludes /TP /D__CUDACC__ /DCMAKE_INTDIR="Debug"
>   /DCMAKE_INTDIR="Debug" /D_MBCS /I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
>   Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\bin" /I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU
>   Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\include" /I. /FIcuda_runtime.h /c
>   C:\Users\me\projects\cuda-test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\main.cu
>       C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\BuildCustomizations\CUDA
>   10.0.targets(536,9): error : **The CUDA Toolkit v10.0 directory 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0\' does not
>   exist.  Please verify the CUDA Toolkit is installed properly or define
>   the CudaToolkitDir property to resolve this error.**
>   [C:\Users\me\projects\cuda-test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_64f0a.vcxproj]
>       Done Building Project "C:\Users\me\projects\cuda-test\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_64f0a.vcxproj"
>   (default targets) -- FAILED.

I'm running Windows 10 with CMake 3.12.0.

Here is the CMakeLists.txt for reference:

> cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8 FATAL_ERROR)
>
> set(CMAKE_CUDA_COMPILER "C:/thirdparty/CUDA/10.0/bin/nvcc.exe")
>   project(cmake_and_cuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)
>
> include(CTest)
>
> add_library(particles STATIC   randomize.cpp   randomize.h
>   particle.cu   particle.h   v3.cu   v3.h   )
>
> # Request that particles be built with -std=c++11
>   # As this is a public compile feature anything that links to particles
>   # will also build with -std=c++11 target_compile_features(particles PUBLIC cxx_std_11)
>
> # We need to explicitly state that we need all CUDA files in the particle
>   # library to be built with -dc as the member functions could be called by
>   # other libraries and executables set_target_properties( particles
>                          PROPERTIES CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON
>                         )
>
> if(BUILD_TESTING)
>
> add_executable(particle_test test.cu)
>
> set_target_properties(particle_test PROPERTIES
>   CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION ON)   target_link_libraries(particle_test
>   PRIVATE particles)
>
> add_test(NAME particles_10k COMMAND particle_test 10000 )
>   add_test(NAME particles_256k COMMAND particle_test 256000 )
>
> if(APPLE)
>       # We need to add the default path to the driver (libcuda.dylib) as an rpath,
>       # so that the static cuda runtime can find it at runtime.
>       set_property(TARGET particle_test PROPERTY BUILD_RPATH ${CMAKE_CUDA_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})   endif() endif()

Comment: Any licensing issue maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I done this on Windows because the build machine does not have Nvidia graphics card and thus not possible to run CUDA installer nor driver installation.

I simply copied the folders from my work PC and added environment variables for:

CUDA Toolkit - CUDA_PATH (C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0)

CUDA Samples - NVCUDASAMPLES_ROOT (C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v10.0)

(depends on what you refeer to in your code projects of course, this is what I needed)

This worked for me on CUDA 9.2 (MVS 2015) and 10.0 (MVS 2017).

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible. The CUDA installation (as opposed to the nVIDIA driver installation) is just a bunch of file on disk. If you're even willing to put them all into a common directory, it really doesn't matter if it's `C:\Program Files\CUDA` (or whatever's the default on Windows) or `C:\thirdparty\cuda`.

Your "only" problem is that your relevant environment variable(s), and perhaps certain registry entries (not sure, since my experience is with Linux). The environment variables *may* (or may not) include some of the following: `CUDA_DIR`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `C_INCLUDE_PATH`, `LIBRARY_PATH`, `CPLUSINCLUDE_PATH`. The environment variables *definitely* include `PATH`.

Caveat: I only have experience with placing CUDA in arbitrary locations on Linux.